# Weird SQLite Behaviour

Tags: android, sqlite

I have been a Java developer for many years and have being developing Android apps for about 6 months.
I have an app that uses a SQLite DB.  The app inserts, updates, deletes and lists table rows in several tables.  All these operations work fine, except occasionally I find the DB no longer contains any table rows.  I can confirm this by using ADB to select from one or more of the tables; no rows exist.  The rows in question have been inserted successfully by the app. I know this because I can use the app's display function to list them and I can run in debug and everything looks right.  I can also run ADB right after inserting rows and the rows exist. Now, for example, if I exit MyEclipse or Android Studio, then restart one of the IDE's and run the app there's no data.  BTW: These are simple single row inserts, using a ContentProvider and I am not enclosing these operations in a Transaction.  I can see from the debug session that the DB is not being recreated.
Does anyone know why the DB is being emptied of content?

Comment: This isn't really answerable without some specific information such as relevant parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just me, but I'm an SQL user too and occasionally forgot to commit - didn't read this here...?

Comment: If he is not using transactions, each operation is automatically enclosed in a transaction and no need to invoke commit()